# How to wait until the CCMenuItemImage is press in objective C?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I want to pause the program until my button is press

I have pause my scene by Use [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause]; sure that the screen is pause but my function is continue running until it end function

Do they have any function to wait for the press button action??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pause the CCDirector, it will drop the framerate to 4 fps - it does not stop the CCDirector from running game updates, nor will it halt the execution of the current method.

Note that the low framerate will affect touch detection and you may find it hard to activate any CCMenu button while CCDirector is paused.

These are just two reasons why CCDirector's pause method is a poor substitute for a **real** implementation of pausing your game. In principle, when you bring up the ingame (pause) menu, what should happen is that any game play object is simply not running any updates and pauses any currently running actions. Only the foreground menu remains running normally to receive user input.